# revert particular commit in git but after this commit there are other commit

Tags: git

My git repository name is alpha. I have changed 5 files and pushed them to the remote repository with commit ID 'B'. Before I commit, the last revision of the repo is 'a'. After my commit, there are more than five commits, like c,d,e, f, etc. My problem is that I want to revert my commit 'b'  but I can't use the git revert commit id because, after my commit, someone released changes to that . Is there any particular command to revert only that commit?
for better understanding

```
f->latest commit
e
d
c
b = my commit that has to be reverted.
a
```

I have tried git revert b,but it reset the file content to the changes before my change.so that will not have latest changes of the file.Is there any other command ??

Comment: in your situation, `git revert b` looks like the easiest solution. Unlinke what you describe, it will just undo the changes in `b`. If these changes happen to overlap with changes in `d .. f` git will trigger a so called *conflict* and will ask you to inspect the content of said files before committing.

Comment: Like noted already, `git revert` basically applies the reverse diff of whatever that commit did. Just use `git log`, copy the hash, try a revert, and hope that you don’t get a merge conflict. But if you do just try to resolve it.